# Fix pre login handshake in Visual Studio C# .NET Maui database connecting to SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, maui

{Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)
---> System.IO.IOException:  Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.d__176`1[[System.Net.Security.SyncReadWriteAdapter, System.Net.Security, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext() at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<ForceAuthenticationAsync>d__175`1[[System.Net.Security.SyncReadWriteAdapter, System.Net.Security, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext()
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.EnableSsl(UInt32 options) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SNI\SNITcpHandle.cs:line 615
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.TdsParserStateObjectManaged.EnableSsl(UInt32& info, Boolean tlsFirst, String serverCertificateFilename) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParserStateObjectManaged.cs:line 372
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnection.cs:line 776 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParser.cs:line 1404 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.EnableSsl(UInt32 info, SqlConnectionEncryptOption encrypt, Boolean integratedSecurity, String serverCertificateFilename) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParser.cs:line 894 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(SqlConnectionEncryptOption encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean& marsCapable, Boolean& fedAuthRequired, Boolean tlsFirst, String serverCert) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParser.cs:line 1059 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Boolean withFailover) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParser.cs:line 528 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:line 1909 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:line 1588 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:line 1436 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:line 528 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnectionFactory.cs:line 136 at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Common\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionFactory.cs:line 123 at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:line 827 at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:line 1761 at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:line 1224 at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:line 1132
at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionFactory.cs:line 122 at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Common\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionInternal.cs:line 350
at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Common\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionClosed.cs:line 39 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnection.cs:line 1844
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnection.cs:line 1341
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() in D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnection.cs:line 1310
at InfoProject.MainPage.ButtonSave(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Projects\InfoProject\InfoProject\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 44
ClientConnectionId:5cf7bd79-9bd7-4a3e-9902-36da4e8dcf19}

```
try
{
    string connectionString = "Data Source=****; Initial Catalog=****; User ID=***; Password=***; Connection Timeout=30; Encrypt=yes; Integrated Security=true;Trust Server Certificate=true; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; ";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Is that the complete error?

Comment: there i edit the full error

Comment: _provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed_. If you can connect via SSMS, what's the output of `SELECT @@VERSION` on the target server? It seems like you're trying to connect to a very old version of SQL Server that doesn't support TLS 1.2, or one in the SQL Server 2008-2014 range that hasn't had service packs and hotfixes applied that enable it. Ref: [KB3135244 - TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe)

Comment: Aside... also, choose one of `User ID` and `Password` or `Integrated Security=true;`. The former pair use SQL Logon authentication, the latter requires Windows Authentication.